# Access VBA SQL Select Query Omit Columns from Result

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Hello everyone hope you are doing well,

I have this query in access

```
"SELECT tbl7Ventas.Periodo, tbl7Ventas.ID_Localidad, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad, tbl5Localidades.RegistroComerciante, tbl7Ventas.Cero_Volumen, tbl7Ventas.Venta_PMT_ALPR, tbl7Ventas.Venta_ST, tbl7Ventas.Servicios_TRCNRPR, tbl7Ventas.Devoluciones_PartidasT, tbl7Ventas.SP_OCPR, tbl7Ventas.SR_CNRPR, tbl7Ventas.SPD_RPR, tbl7Ventas.SR_PDNRPR, tbl7Ventas.Ventas_PMT_Exenta, tbl7Ventas.Ventas_SE, tbl7Ventas.Devolucion_PE 
FROM tbl7Ventas INNER JOIN tbl5Localidades ON tbl7Ventas.ID_Localidad = tbl5Localidades.ID
WHERE MONTH(tbl7Ventas.Periodo) = Month(2/22/2019) 
AND YEAR(tbl7Ventas.Periodo) = Year(2/22/2019)
AND tbl7Ventas.ID_Localidad = "Estacion Numero Uno"
```

Everything works well when I run it but I need to exclude

`tbl7Ventas.Periodo, tbl7Ventas.ID_Localidad, tbl5Localidades.NombreLocalidad`

from the results of the query.

I've been reading and reading but have not found an answer yet and was hoping someone out there could help me out.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You don't need to select a column in order to use it in a join or in a where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this query is hand-written (go to SQL view in the query view) type in:

```
SELECT  tbl5Localidades.RegistroComerciante, tbl7Ventas.Cero_Volumen, tbl7Ventas.Venta_PMT_ALPR, tbl7Ventas.Venta_ST, tbl7Ventas.Servicios_TRCNRPR, tbl7Ventas.Devoluciones_PartidasT, tbl7Ventas.SP_OCPR, tbl7Ventas.SR_CNRPR, tbl7Ventas.SPD_RPR, tbl7Ventas.SR_PDNRPR, tbl7Ventas.Ventas_PMT_Exenta, tbl7Ventas.Ventas_SE, tbl7Ventas.Devolucion_PE 
FROM tbl7Ventas INNER JOIN tbl5Localidades ON tbl7Ventas.ID_Localidad = tbl5Localidades.ID
WHERE MONTH(tbl7Ventas.Periodo) = Month(2/22/2019) 
AND YEAR(tbl7Ventas.Periodo) = Year(2/22/2019)
AND tbl7Ventas.ID_Localidad = "Estacion Numero Uno"
```

If not just go to the "query view" and uncheck the columns you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have tried this before but then I'm not able to get the information from the columns on the inner join.

Comment: @SantiagoA.Beltrán - you keep the column, you just don't display them. In the query view you uncheck the display (but you keep the column because of the join!). If you're in SQL view then copy the code - it should work, which version of MS-Access are you using?

Comment: I'm using Access 2016. At first I thought that was the most obvious approach but then I'm not able to pull data from those columns.

Comment: OMG Hila it does work but for some reason my textboxes are not getting the data but I exported the results from the query to an excel to verify and thats precisely what I wanted. Its just that in the textboxes maybe I got something mixed up there.